# Recalculate Quantile Breakpoints in CalculateField_management loop?

Tags: python, arcmap, symbology

I have a program that iteratively replaces a temp field where I choose a certain symbology (color ramp and quantile color break methodology) with a few other fields from a join. The program works in that it outputs a file with the correct formatting and such, but it doesn't recalculate the quantile breakpoints based on the new fields. Is it possible to have it recalculate this?

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

#List of names of fields to be mapped
ListOfFieldsToSymbolize = ["beta1","beta2","beta3"]

#Temporary field that layer is currently using in ArcMap
SymbolizedField = "temp"

for Field in ListOfFieldsToSymbolize:

    #Replace temporary field with one of the fields to be mapped
    arcpy.CalculateField_management("HRR_Boundary", SymbolizedField, "!" + Field + "!", "PYTHON")    

    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, Field)
```